# Linux Mint 18: my Dell Precision 5520 reboots from suspend instead of waking up

Tags: linux-mint, suspend

This is a regression from Mint 17.3, where suspend/resume worked just fine on that same machine (using a series 4.2 kernel -- Mint 18 comes with a series 4.4 kernel).  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I have a brand new Dell Precision 5520 and am running Ubuntu 17.04.
After suspend, when attempting to resume by pressing the power button, the machine would reboot.

I was searching, trying to figure out what caused this and came across this thread.   I checked my BIOS and was at 1.2.4.  Dell's latest was 1.3.3.  I downloaded and installed.  Resume now works as expected with Ubuntu 17.04.  I suspend and after the machine sleeps, I press the power button and it resumes back to the Ubuntu login prompt (which it displays, then the screen goes completely black for a moment, and then displays the login prompt again).  After entering my password, I get back to the desktop in the same state I left it in before I suspended.

Comment: If this is essentially the same path as the other answer, the StackExchange way is to upvote the other answer.

Comment: This was originally reported almost 6 months ago and units are still shipping with the old BIOS that has the problem. I also provided exact version numbers with and without the problem. I also confirmed the assertion that the BIOS is the cause. For these reasons, I felt that a simple upvote was not sufficient. I did upvote the other answer, but it does not show up because I do not have enough reputation. I would agree that the information I provided could have been added as a comment but I don't have enough reputation for that. The only way I have available to respond here is with an answer.

Answer (score 0):

First, check if you are running the most recent BIOS. Depending on the hardware, this may fix a lot of issues and you also need it to file a bug report.

I am not sure about which Ubuntu version Mint 18 corresponds too, but if you have a standard setup, and the problem persists, you can file a bug report on launchpad. Please update the BIOS before doing that.

There is also a patch in the waiting, maybe you have to await that:
https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/9402601/

or apply the patch yourself and compile a kernel as described (just Google, I can only post 1 link because of reputation).
Check the bug report mentioned there, you may be able to help out.

You could try Dell support too, because it seems like a BIOS bug, but they would have to support Linux on it to be able to help.

Please post how it goes, good luck!